# How can I force the specs2 tests to stop right after one of the tests failed

Tags: playframework-2.0, functional-testing, specs2

I'm testing a play2 project by using specs2. How can I force the test to stop right after one of the tests failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place `args(stopOnFail=true)` in your `Specification`, which will cause all other tests within the spec to be skipped after the first failure. Note that this will only skip remaining tests within the `Specification`, and not all of the specs.

```
object TestSpec extends Specification {

    args(stopOnFail=true)

    // fails
    "must fail" in {
        true must beFalse
    }

    // is skipped
    "must be arbitrary" in {
        1 must equalTo(0)
    }
}
```

I'm not aware of any way to skip all specs after failure. Here's a references for the above: [Specs2 Runners](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#API)